# Visual Studio Team Explorer: Customize the "My Work" pane

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

Is there a way to customize the "My Work" pane to show more groups?

For instance, I currently have In Progress Work, Suspended Work, and Available Work Items. I also have a "Code Reviews" section. How could I add a section for "Bugs ready to test" or something along those lines?

I ask this because I have work items in my queue that don't appear on this list - it seems as though Tasks do, but Bugs do not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the Available Work Items section to show the results of any query you want.  Just create a query that shows what you're interested in, and save it in My Queries.  Then in the My Work pane you can select it from the drop-down:

[image]

Comment: Is the "Current Iteration - ..." option available only with TFS 2015 ? I only get "All Iterations - All Teams"

Comment: Still works in VS2017. For me the key was that the work item query had to be saved under "My Queries". Does not show up if saved as a shared query.